# XFCE4 Missing Indicator Icons for Apps

Tags: indicator, xfce

I have had this problem now with two apps, they both use the `libappindicator` to display their indicator icons (I believe). First time I had this problem was with `Ubuntuone-indicator` app, now I have this same problem with Sparkleshare, so I figure it must be related. I just recompiled and installed sparkleshare 1.0 from source last night, thought that might be the problem. Still same thing.

All works fine in Gnome, but once I go into XFCE it give me the missing icon problem. Could it be as simple as an icon out of place? If so where do I move the icons to?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your theme/icon pack doesn't know where those icons are.  Easiest way to fix it is to just specify which icon to use.

I added a .icons and .themes folder to my home dir and dropped icons in there.

If you don't want to change the icons set you can go to the one you want to change and edit it directly in `/user/share/icons/<setname>`

Comment: Well all their icons are in that folder under `hicolor` and `gnome`. I've tried copying those two folders and the icons files themselves into my `.icons` folder but still doesn't find them. This is my `.icons` folder: http://i.imgur.com/1FVHz41.png

Comment: Hm. Possibly check `/usr/share/pixmaps` That's kinda the default icons folder.

Comment: Yeah, they are all in that folder. Can I make my own Pixmaps folder then as I did icons and themes?

Comment: That's what .icons is for. I just readded my volume indicator and it assumed the icon from the set I am using.  Possibly try pulling and readding the indicator?

Comment: Yeah, tried that also and it still doesn't accept it either.

Answer (score 0):

If you've copied icons to a different folder (or simply added/updated icons) you'll need to update the icon cache: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gtk-update-icon-cache.1.html